# Finding a specific term in an expansion $(a+b)^n$ without expanding

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I find a term within an expansion without actually expanding or using Pascal's Triangle?

For example: 5th term of 
$$
\left(\dfrac{x}{y}-\dfrac{y}{x}\right)^8
$$

Comment: [Binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)

Answer (score 3):

Do you know the Binomial Theorem? It states:

$$(a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \begin{pmatrix} n \\ k \end{pmatrix} a^kb^{n-k}.$$

Simply pick the $k$th term. (Or $k-1$th term depending on whether you consider $k=0$ to be the first term).

Comment: He's algebra level. Could you explain it a *way* simpler fashion?

Comment: @DantheMan The tag is [tag:algebra-precalculus], the basics of the binomial expansion, along with binomial coefficients, is/should be standard in a precalculus curriculum, and "binomial" is part of the tag wiki. The OP is always free to ask questions if he doesn't fully understand.

Answer (score 0):

$$(a+b)^n=\binom{n}{0}a^nb^0 +\binom{n}{1}a^{n-1}b^1+\binom{n}{2}a^{n-2}b^2+\binom{n}{3}a^{n-3}b^3+....\\so\\5th\\term\\is\\\binom{n}{4}a^{n-4}b^4\\(\frac{x}{y}-\frac{y}{x})^8\\5th-term\\
 \binom{8}{4}(\frac{x}{y})^{8-4}(-\frac{y}{x})^4=\\\frac{8*7*6*5}{4*3*2*1}(\frac{x}{y})^{4}(\frac{y}{x})^4=\\\frac{8*7*6*5}{4*3*2*1} $$